# Repeated Numpy Array Dot Products

Tags: python, numpy, dot-product

Let's presume that we have numpy arrays `A.shape = (1, 2)` and `B.shape = (2, 2)` and a count `X`.

If `X = 1`, we want the result = `A.dot(B)`

If `X = 2`, we want the result = `(A.dot(B)).dot(B)`

If `X = 3`, we want the result = `((A.dot(B)).dot(B)).dot(B)`

How can we write a function in Python that gives us the correct result based 9n `X`?  Tried to loop through the dot products based upon `X`, but the code is very messy and not working properly.

Comment: Have you made any effort to solve this yourself?

Comment: Pseudo code: loop `x` times and take the dot product each time, return the overall result

Comment: @Henry. Sorry, I couldn't resist. There's a no-loop solution

Comment: @MadPhysicist Neat! There's a reason I shouldn't be answering questions.

Comment: @Henry. I feel really bad posting any answer for a question like that.

Comment: "but the code is very messy and not working properly." - You have an answer now, but for the future please do post some code to show us what you've tried, and we can help you fix it. I'd guess a fair number of the down votes are because you didn't post any of your own attempts.

Comment: The loop should be as simple as `for _ in range(X): A = A.dot(B)`. If you'd shown us your attempt, we could help you fix it, but trying to explain what you might have gotten wrong in that loop without knowing what you actually got wrong is next to impossible.

Comment: @Henry Think about it this way: `dot` is a kind of multiplication. Exponentiation is just repeated multiplication, right? (Well, wrong if you're dealing with, say, complex numbers… but we're dealing with matrices as bases and natural numbers as exponents.) So it's probably worth looking for some kind of exponentiation-based answer. Which may be hard to find in the docs, but it's easy to find in Mad Physicist's brain. So all you need is to index that brain for searches… and that's basically what SO is. :)

Comment: @abarnert "Which may be hard to find in the docs". Strictly speaking probably true, because I'd never heard of that function before. On the other hand I just assumed it exists and Googled.

Answer (score 3):

One liner using matrix multiplication commutativity and [`matrix_power`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.matrix_power.html):

```
A.dot(np.linalg.matrix_power(B, X))
```